# How to count when there are multiple WHERE statements

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have three tables with following details.

Table 1 : Products - Columns : Product Name, Price, Product ID

Table 2 : Customers - Columns : Customer Name, Customer ID, City

Table 3 : Orders - Columns : Order ID, Customer ID, Product ID

What should be the query for following scenario?

Scenario:
Need to display customer name, no.of orders by respective customer, Total Price Paid (sum of all orders by respective customer).

Comment: I'm novice in SQL queries and I tried to write a lot of queries using Select and Where statements but had miserable errors

Comment: Thanks to everyone for providing the right answers. Every answer worked perfectly. Many Thanks again.

Comment: I really didn't make anyone else do my work. I was practising SQL queries on SQLzoo.net overnight. After first few miserable tries I posted a question here. After getting help through these answers I completed two complete exercises there. I seriously do not see any wrongdoing in asking something which I didn't understand even after referring to multiple queries in that tutorial. By giving my own table and scenario I understood how SQL query works and how relations between table are made. Sorry if I'm offending you, but I don't mean to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select c.customer_name, x.no_of_orders, y.total_price from customer c
left join (
    select customer_id, COUNT(customer_id) as no_of_orders from orders 
    group by customer_id) x on c.customer_id = x.customer_id
left join (
    select o.customer_id, SUM(p.price) as total_price from order o 
    inner join products p on o.productid = p.productid
    group by customer_id) y on c.customer_id = y.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT c.CustomerName,
    count(o.orderId) [Orders Count],
    SUM(p.Price) [Total Price]
FROM CUSTOMERS c
    JOIN ORDERS o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    JOIN PRODUCTS p ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY c.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.name,COUNT(o.id),SUM(p.price)
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = o.product_id
GROUP BY c.name;
```

You JOIN customers with orders with customer_id; Then you JOIN orders with products with product_id.

Then you simply GROUP BY c.name to get the aggregated values of COUNT(o.id) and SUM(p.price) for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT c.[Customer Name], COUNT(DISTINCT o.[Order ID]), SUM(p.Price)
FROM Customers AS c
JOIN Orders AS o ON c.[Customer ID] = o.[Customer ID]
JOIN Products AS p ON o.[Product ID] = p.[Product ID]
GROUP BY c.[Customer Name]
```

The only problem is it appears that the `Orders` table is missing a `Quantity` field.  So, in the above example I am simply summing up the price.

Also, to get a count of the orders per customer I used distinct inside the COUNT() function.  You will need to do this if a single order can point to multiple products.  Otherwise you can remove it.